# Make a bar plot with positive and negative values

Tags: r, ggplot2

Having a dataframe like this:

```
data.frame(names = c("yahoo", "google", "amazon", "aliexpress"), frq = c(3,1,-4,-1))
```

How is it possible to make a plot to have the positive names into one side and the negative from the other?

Something like [this](https://juliasilge.com/blog/2018/2018-05-18-stack-overflow-pca_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-8-1.png) plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
  library(ggplot2)
  df <- data.frame(names = c("yahoo", "google", "amazon", "aliexpress"), frq = c(3,1,-4,-1))
        
  ggplot(df, aes(x=names, y=frq, fill=names)) + 
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = df$names)+ theme(legend.position="none")+
  xlab("Names") +
  ylab("Frequency")
```

[image]

## Update

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=names, y=frq)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = frq < 0), stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(guide = FALSE, breaks = c(TRUE, FALSE), values=c("Green", "red")) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = df$names)+ theme(legend.position="none")+
  xlab("Names") +
  ylab("Frequency")
```

[image]

Comment: if you arrange the df first accoring to ```frq```, you can add ```+  scale_x_discrete(limits = df$names)``` to order the bars from the lowest value to the highest value

Comment: thank you nice. Could it be possible to have one colour i.e red for positive frq and blue for negative?

Comment: @foc See my update now. Don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just order the factors according to frequency:

```
library(ggplot2)
h <- data.frame(names = c("yahoo", "google", "amazon", "aliexpress"), frq = c(3,1,-4,-1))

h$names <- factor(h$names, levels = h$names[order(h$frq)])
h$positive <- ifelse(h$frq>0, 1, 0)

ggplot(h, aes(names, frq, fill=positive)) + geom_bar( stat = "identity")
```